# How to create a stopwatch time column (running clock) in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I was hoping to get a column to add in my data frame that would be a running clock in seconds, but look like a timestamp.  The column created would look like:

```
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
00:00:05
.... Until every row is completed
```

Any suggestions is helpful.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: I need to sync the file it with a video that only has timestamps in another external program.  Adding that column allows for that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's probably simpler to use the ready-made function `as.hms` that MKR's solution shows, it's not too hard to write your own function for this. Which may be more instructive, and does avoid dependencies.

```
stopwatch = function(x) {
  sprintf('%02i:%02i:%02i', (x%/%3600), (x%/%60) %% 60, x%%60)
}
stopwatch(1:10)

# [1] "00:00:01" "00:00:02" "00:00:03" "00:00:04" "00:00:05" "00:00:06" "00:00:07" "00:00:08"
# [9] "00:00:09" "00:00:10"
```

Comment: @AndrewKaplan - I had another look and realised this could be simplifed. See the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

The one solution is to use `row_number` as seconds and convert it as hour:min:sec.

**Solution 1:**

```
 df <- data.frame(sl = 1:1000, value = runif(20, 200, 1000))

  df$stopwatch <- row_number()

  library(lubridate)
  library(dplyr)


  df %>% mutate(stopwatch = seconds_to_period(row_number()))

#       sl    value stopwatch
#..........
#58     58 482.6169       58S
#59     59 706.1599       59S
#60     60 498.2112     1M 0S
#61     61 473.2637     1M 1S
$62     62 843.2440     1M 2S
...........
```

**Solution 2:**
 Use `hms` package:

```
  df %>% mutate(stopwatch = hms::as.hms(row_number()))
       sl    value stopwatch
1       1 473.2637  00:00:01
2       2 843.2440  00:00:02
3       3 864.1852  00:00:03
4       4 854.0714  00:00:04
5       5 425.9075  00:00:05
6       6 505.4091  00:00:06
7       7 507.7273  00:00:07
8       8 440.8840  00:00:08
```

Comment: @dww Thanks for pointing out. I changed function last moment. I got it corrected now.